# validating ip address in datastage

Tags: validation, ip, datastage

I have a source file that contains two fields: **IP_ADDRESS** and **USER_NAME**. I want to check whether the IP address is correct or not before loading it to the datawarehouse using DATASTAGE. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I was browsing Stack Overflow and think I might have a solution to your question. If you create a job to grab all of the IP_ADDRESS's from the file and send them to a BASIC transformer (search for BASIC transformer in DataStage. It is NOT the one that is normally on the palette). From there, set the Stage Variables as 'SetUserStatus() and write out the column name to a peek stage (You don't need the output at all. The SetUserStatus is the important part). This will now allow you to pass up the Command Output (list of IP Addresses) to a Sequence. From the Sequence, start with the job you just created (BASIC transformer job) and link that to a User Variables Activity. In the User Variables Activity stage, Set the name to something like 'IP Address' and Expression as IP_ADDRESS.$UserStatus. You can then use a Loop to take that output that is now a List and send each individual IP Address to an Execute Stage with a Ping command to see if it returns a valid IP Address. If it does return a valid IP then have your job that writes the USER_NAME and IP_ADDRESS to do a 'Select' statement where the IP_ADDRESS = the valid IP_ADDRESS. For the ones that aren't valid, you can send them down a different path and have them write out to '.txt' file somewhere so you know which ones weren't valid. I'm sure you will need a few more steps in there but that should be the gist of it.

Hope my quick stab at your issue helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a transformer or a transformer and a filter to do that, depending on the version of Datastage you're using. If you're using PX, just encode the validation logic in a transformer stage, and then, on  the output link set up a filter that doesn't allow the rows to pass forward if they didn't pass the validation logic.